# AudioFileReadPackets deprecated in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avaudiofile

I am getting strange behaviour with AudioFileReadPackets since it's been deprecated in iOS 8.
How should it be replaced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Apple's [Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileReadPackets)

AudioFileReadPackets is deprecated in iOS 8.0 . You can try [this:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileReadPacketData) `AudioFileReadPacketData`

> If you do not need to read a fixed duration of audio data, but rather
>   want to use your memory buffer most efficiently, use
>   `AudioFileReadPacketData` instead of `AudioFileReadPackets` .When reading variable
>   bit-rate (VBR) audio data, using `AudioFileReadPackets` function requires that you
>   allocate more memory than you would for the AudioFileReadPacketData
>   function. See the descriptions for the outBuffer parameter in each of
>   these two functions. In addition, `AudioFileReadPackets` function is less efficient than
>   `AudioFileReadPacketData` when reading compressed file formats that do
>   not have packet tables, such as MP3 or ADTS. Use this function only
>   when you need to read a fixed duration of audio data, or when you are
>   reading only uncompressed audio.
>
> ```
> Audio File Services reads one 32-bit chunk of a file at a time.
> ```